# What would roughly be the function of these graphs?

Tags: functions, graphing-functions

Questions like this has probably been asked alot, however google was unable to aid me, so im asking here.

In the following picture of 2 graphs, im trying to find the approximate function of the below graphs, aswell as their signs and zeros. however, i've been unable to figure out how to read the functions of below graphs and hope you can help me

[image: Graphs]

Answer (score 0):

The first one, try $f(x) = Ce^{\frac{-(x-a)^2}{b}}$. The second $g(x)=ax^4 +bx^3 + cx^2 +dx +m$.

Now go to wolframalpha and write plot function. Where at function you put the **actual** function. Play around with values of the coefficient. This way you will understand what role they play.

For the second one you know where you have max/min, this you can use to find suitable values of the coefficients.

Comment: Thanks! I will do so :)

Answer (score 0):

The first is either $$y=\frac{1}{1+ax^2}$$ or $$y=e^{-ax^2}$$ where $a$ is a constant.

The second is a negative quartic function, so something of the form $y=ax^4+bx^3+cx+d$ where $a$ is negative and $d$ is between $0$ and $0.5$